# Is the transformation implied by a positive-type kernel well-defined?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

I’ve been trying to get my head around the particularity of the Hilbert space that a positive-type (equiv. positive definite) kernel represents an inner product on, and  was hoping for some help in validating the following logic. I use the support vector machine scenario to land the problem, but this stands in for any problem involving a positive-type kernel.

Consider the following theorem: $^1$

A complex function $K$ defined on $E\times E$ is a reproducing kernel or a positive-type function if and only if there exists a mapping $T$ from $E$ to some space $l^2(X)$ such that

$$\forall(x,y)\in E\times E\hspace{0.8cm} K(x,y)=\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle_{l^2(X)}=\sum_{\alpha\in X}(T(x))_\alpha(T(y))_\alpha$$

Since there is an isometry from any Hilbert space to $l^2$ (up to separability), by the uniqueness of the inner product associated with its induced metric it is sufficient to establish the above equality for any Hilbert space (or indeed inner product space, via completion).

The above is coherent because the Theorem does not state *on which* space the kernel possesses the reproducing property. Indeed the *Moore-Aronszajn Theorem* shows that a positive-type function is a reproducing kernel on exactly *one* Hilbert space.

Now, the generalisation of support vector machines to kernels does not appear to make use of the reproducing property. (The *Representer Theorem* does, but this per se makes it a sufficient rather than necessary property.)  The following statement proceeds from this reasoning:

*In fitting a kernel support vector machine, we are constructing infinitely many equivalent hyperplanes, each in a distinct Hilbert space defined by a unique transformation, and using the inner product implied by this transformation.*

One corollary would be that the inner product and transformation utilised in fitting the support vector machine is not well-defined, but refers to a collection. (Can we state an algebraic structure for this collection without additional conditions?) Another is that on one of the feature spaces in question $K$ is indeed a reproducing kernel.

$^1$Theorem 4, *Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces in Probability and Statistics*, Berlinet & Thomas-Agnan, 2004.